# swagger-api does not work swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swagger, swagger-codegen

Swagger-api in swift gives me an error and I don't know how to solve it.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
This is the link from where I am downloading swagger-api. After the download I unzip it. Open the unzipped folder > samples > client > petstore > swift3. There are three demo's in this folder i.e (default, promisekit and rxSwift). When I try to open it and run it, gives me an error 'Use of undeclared type 'OuterEnum' and Use of undeclared type 'ClassModel'. I don't know how to solve it. Please anyone can help me to run this code.